# Why use useDelimiter(Pattern pattern) vs useDelimiter(String pattern)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

According the java:

> public Scanner useDelimiter(String pattern) Sets this scanner's
>   delimiting pattern to a pattern constructed from the specified String.
>   An invocation of this method of the form useDelimiter(pattern) behaves
>   in exactly the same way as the invocation
>   useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(pattern)).

Is there any advantage to using `Pattern.compile(pattern)`? I have read that `Pattern.compile(pattern)` will place the compiled pattern in memory thereby making scanner searches faster. Will `useDelimiter(String pattern)` also place the pattern in memory?

In short, do they really behave exactly the same way?

Answer (score 1):

`useDelimiter(String)` may be even more efficient than `useDelimiter(Pattern)` because it not only compiles the pattern as with `Pattern.compile(String)` but it also caches up to 7 compiled patterns and simply looks them up. If you regularly use more than 7 patterns, though, you'll get caching churn which might degrade the performance and so you may be better off compiling and caching the patterns yourself.

Comment: Small point, but this won't be *more* efficient unless you're Doing It Wrong - the `String` version still has to look up the pattern in the cache. If you're compiling the pattern once, storing it yourself and reusing it, it will be very slightly more performant than the `String` variant, even in best-case scenario for the latter.